# How do you show that the language L= { $ a^nb^nc^na^kb^lc^m : k,l,m,n >0 $ } is not a cfg?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I understand how for the language $ a^nb^nc^n $ it is a straightforward application of the pumping lemma, but the part after that seems to exclude the possibility of using the pumping lemma. I would like to know whether there is some way of using any closure property to do the same. Also is there some stronger version of the pumping lemma where it could be applied to some subset of the string rather than the entire string? I mean if we could just apply the pumping lemma on the $ a^nb^nc^n $ out of the $ a^nb^nc^na^kb^lc^m $ ?

Comment: I don't know if there is some stronger version of the pumping lemma as you mentioned, but the usual pumping lemma should work here as well.

Comment: Could you give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $p$ is the pumping length, apply the pumping lemma to the word $a^pb^pc^pabc$ and pump down.

Comment: Hi, but the pumping length can be 2 and it could be ab or bc, right?

Comment: @user2277550: Doesn’t matter. If the word breaks down as $uvxyz$, where $|vxy|\le p$, $|vy|\ge 1$, and $uv^kxy^kz\in L$ for all $k\ge 0$, setting $k=0$ gives you $uxz$, which is not in $L$ no matter where the $vxy$ block is. Remember, $a^pb^pc^pa$, for instance, is not in $L$: $k.\ell$, and $m$ must all be **positive**. That’s why you pump down to $k=0$ and not up.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the part about k being able to be zero.

Comment: @user2277550: You’re welcome.

Comment: Can you pump down if replace k,l,m,n $>$ with $>=$ ? In that case is there an alternate way to prove that the language is not in cfg?

Comment: @user2277550: (Sorry to be so slow.) I don’t at the moment see a way to use the pumping lemma if we allow $k,\ell,m$, and $n$ to be $0$. However, one can use the [fact](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20090/closure-of-cfl-against-right-quotient-with-regular-languages) that context-free languages are closed under (right) quotients with regular languages. Let $L_1$ be the modified language and $R=\left\{a^kb^\ell c^m:k,\ell,m\ge 0\right\}$; then $$L_1/R=\left\{a^nb^nc^n:n\ge 0\right\}\,,$$ which we know is not context-free, so $L_1$ is not context-free.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I actually found out a way to use pumping lemma in the case where $k,l,m,n >= 0$. Just apply the pumping lemma on $a^nb^nc^n$. This is a valid string since $k,m,n$ can be zero.

Comment: @user2277550: You’re welcome. If you allow $n$ to be $0$, applying the pumping lemma to $a^pb^pc^p$ won’t work: no matter how you pump, you’ll get something of the form $a^kb^\ell c^m$, which is in the language.