# How do you show that the language $L= \{ a^nb^nc^na^kb^lc^m \mid l,m,n \geqslant 0 \text{ and } k >0 \}$ is not context-free.

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

This is somewhat similar to another question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971244/how-do-you-show-that-the-language-l-anbncnakblcm-k-l-m-n-0-is/3971921#3971921). In that case you could apply the pumping lemma by pumping down on $a^nb^nc^nabc$ . However when $>$ is replaced by $\geq$ for all $\{k,l,m,n\}$, I think that option is no longer available. However, then you can pump up on $a^nb^nc^n$ and prove the required result quite easily. To cut off that possibility, just one power variable of $a^kb^lc^m$, i.e. one of $\{k,l,m\}$, in this case is kept to be greater than $0$, i.e. $k>0$. Can this grammar be shown to be not in cfg?

Comment: I don't see any difference with the previous question.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to work that out after I posted this. Here you can pump down on $a^nb^nc^na$ right? If that is the answer, maybe I should delete this question?

Comment: The title of the two questions is exactly the same, so I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Oh sorry. I made a small mistake in the title.

Comment: What about $k$? Do you want it to be also $\geqslant 0$?

Comment: No, I want just k to be > 0, to avoid the $a^nb^nc^n$ case, which can be shown to be not in CFG quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $L$ is context-free. Then its intersection with the regular language $a^+b^+c^+a$ is also context-free. But
$$
L \cap a^+b^+c^+a = \{a^nb^nc^na \mid n > 0\}
$$
and you apparently already know how to handle this case. Thus $L$ is not context-free.